# Responsive => DESKTOP screen

Tags: html, css

[image: This is how I want it to look like.]I am stuck with responsive, to be more precise, with desktop screen of 1440px(90em).Does not really matter which size, but when I try to make it responsive(desktop), my tip calculator always looks somehow weird.I am not much experienced with CSS, thus these kind of problems occur every now and then.Anybody can check this project(code) and let some hints/tips go my way? :)

```
HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Tip calculator app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main__container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="input__container">
      <label for="bill"><span>Bill</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="input__count">
      <img src="./images/icon-dollar.svg" alt="person icon" class="img__dollar">
    </div>
    <div class="tip__container">
      <h2>Select Tip %</h2>
      <div class="tip__numbers">
        <span>5%</span>
        <span>10%</span>
        <span>15%</span>
        <span>25%</span>
        <span>50%</span>
        <input placeholder="Custom">Custom</input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
      <span>Number of people</span>
      <span class="error__info">Can't be zero</span>
      <img src="./images/icon-person.svg" alt="person icon" class="img__person">
      <input type="text" class="input__people">
      <div class="result__numbers">
        <div class="result__numbers__container">
          <span class="text__white">Tip Amount</span>
          <span class="text__cyan">/ person</span>
        </div>
        <div class="result__tip__number">
          <span>$0.00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="result__numbers__container">
          <span class="text__white">Total</span>
          <span class="text__cyan">/ person</span>
        </div>
        <div class="result__tip__number">
          <span class="result__total__number">$0.00</span>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="btn__reset">Reset</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>


CSS code:




 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono:wght@400;700&display=swap');

:root {
    --bg-color: rgba(184, 181, 181, 0.788);
    --strong-cyan: hsl(172, 67%, 45%);
    --very-dark-cyan: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
    --dark-grayish-cyan: hsl(186, 14%, 43%);
    --dark-grayish-cyan-2: hsl(184, 14%, 56%);
    --light-grayish-cyan: hsl(185, 41%, 84%);
    --light-grayish-cyan-2: hsl(189, 41%, 97%);
    --white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);

    --inp-font-size: 2.4em;
}

/* MOBILE FIRST DESIGN */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.main__container {
    background: hsl(185, 41%, 84%);
    min-height: 90vh;
    width: 20em;
    /* !!! */

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

// @media (min-width: 90em) {
//     .main__container {
//         width: 100%;
//     }
// }

.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 2em;
}

.input__container,
.tip__container {
    background: var(--white);
    width: 100%;
}

.input__container {
    height: 10vh;
    border-top-left-radius: 2em;
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
    padding: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 4.5em;

    position: relative;
}

.input__container span {
    display: block;
    color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
    font-weight: 700;
}

.input__count {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: var(--light-grayish-cyan-2);
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 3.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
    font-weight: 700;
}

.input__count:hover,
.input__count:focus {
    border: 3px solid var(--strong-cyan);
}

.input__container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 15%;
    height: 20%;
}

.tip__container {
    height: 20vh;
}

// @media (min-width: 90em) {
//     .tip__container {
//       display: flex;
// }

.tip__container h2 {
    color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 2em 0em 1em 1.5em;
}

.tip__numbers {
    padding: 1.5em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% auto;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 2em);
    gap: 0.5em;
}

.tip__numbers span {
    background: var(--very-dark-cyan);
    color: var(--white);
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.2em 0em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tip__numbers span:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #84fab0 0%, #8fd3f4 100%);
}

.tip__numbers span:last-child {
    background: var(--light-grayish-cyan-2);
    color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
}

.tip__numbers span:nth-child(3) {
    /* --> ACTIVE TIP PERCENTAGE <--*/
    background: var(--strong-cyan);
    color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
}

.tip__numbers input {
    background: var(--light-grayish-cyan-2);
    color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
    font-weight: 700;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.tip__numbers input:hover,
.tip__numbers input:focus {
    border: 3px solid var(--strong-cyan);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

input::placeholder {
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.result {
    height: 50vh;
    padding: 1.5em;
    background: var(--white);
    width: 100%;

    position: relative;
}

.result > span {
    color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
    font-weight: 700;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.result .error__info {
    color: orange;
    margin-left: 2.5em;
}

.input__people {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: var(--light-grayish-cyan-2);
    color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 7.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.img__person {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 12%;
    left: 16%;
}

.result__numbers {
    background: var(--very-dark-cyan);
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    padding: 1.5em 1em;
    width: 19em;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% auto;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.result__numbers__container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    width: 7em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.text__white {
    color: var(--white);
}

.text__cyan {
    color: var(--dark-grayish-cyan);
    font-size: 0.6em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.result__tip__number {
    margin-left: 4em;
    color: var(--strong-cyan);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.btn__reset {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: var(--strong-cyan);
    color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    width: 17em;
}

.btn__reset:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #84fab0 0%, #8fd3f4 100%);
}
```

Comment: *always looks somehow weird*, can you give an example how you want it to be or what kind of weird?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post image of how I want it to look like.Now you can check it, I have added image in my post(edited).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick hint use media queries to adjust to smaller screens or for bigger screens

Like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
   //Here you put your css for everything less then 992px
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px){
   //Here you put your css for everything less then 760px
}

//etc.
```

or/and use percentage instead of strict sizes where it make sense

or/and use vw and vh instead of script sizes where it makes sense ("1vw" equals a 1 percent of screen size width, "1vh" is 1 percent of screen height)

or/and consider to use image instead of css for this calulator if it's just a n picture and doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that every think betwen that screen size it's going to be re-style
dont use px to set the css (em,vh,%,rem)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 992px) {
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 720px) {
}
```

Comment: Hello Mate. Just an advice.  When making a mobile first design, we do not to use media query going from 1px to say 720px, as you have mentioned. Instead we create the app for mobile design without the media query and then from onward use media query as the screen size increases. Cheers !!!